# Как поменять местами элементы DOM-дерева?

Tags: javascript, dom, дерево

Предположим, что у нас есть два узла DOM-дерева, такие,
что ни один из них не находится в поддереве у другого, например 3 и 9.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в общем случае вполне поменять местами такие узлы DOM?

```
function swap(node1: Element, node2: Element) {
}
```

Comment: @UModeL Я имел в виду **самый общий случай**, то есть, в частности, когда у узлов есть и потомки, и обработчики, которые надо сохранить. Предполагая, что ни один из узлов не является поддеревом, находящемся внутри другого.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732624/how-to-swap-dom-child-nodes-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так как нужно лишь поменять местами, достаточно выполнить один [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild), который возвращает заменяемый узел и вставить этот узел в место, где был первый.

Для правильной вставки можно использовать [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). Чтобы найти узел перед которым надо вставить можно воспользоваться свойством [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)

В случае, когда узлы идут друг за другом, достаточно просто воспользоваться [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) на этих узлах.

Пример:

```js
function swap(node1, node2) {
  var node1Next = node1.nextElementSibling;
  if (node1Next == node2) {
    node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node2, node1);
    return;
  }

  node1.parentNode.insertBefore(node2.parentNode.replaceChild(node1, node2), node1Next);
}
swap(document.querySelector('.wrap1'), document.querySelector('.wrap2'));
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">wrap1</div>
<div class="wrap2">wrap2</div>
<div class="">skip1</div>
<div class="">skip2</div>
<div class="">skip3</div>
<div class="wrap3">wrap3</div>
<div class="wrap4">wrap4</div>
```

Comment: Тут уже код получается завязан на существование `node1.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш нет не завязан. Если `nextElementSibling` пустой, значит элемент последний на уровне, `insertBefore` в случае, если второй параметр `null` вставит в конец. Таким образом положение будет верным. Подробнее про работу указанных методов смотри по ссылкам в ответе.

Comment: Вообще-то в вашем решении нельзя `wrap1` и `wrap2` поменять и местами, например.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш: это потому, что Вы удалили упоминание про несоседние элементы (3 и 13). Я для этого ранее уточнял.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш, да, с соседними элементами достаточно использовать `insertBefore` без каких-либо дополнений. Обновил ответ

Comment: @UModeL, не это потому что я не проверял подряд идущие :) проверил только что последний элемент нормально меняется

Comment: @UModeL Данное решение ведь как раз не может работать **с соседними узлами**, такими как 3 и 9.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш, обновленное - может ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @UModeL, зачем удалил-то ответ?

Comment: @Grundy: мой ответ не в полной мере подходил ТС, он имел в виду что-то, чего я не понял. Считайте меня "охотником за галочками" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Решение на основе симметричной пары ссылок:

```js
function swap(node1, node2) {
  const parent1 = node1.parentNode
  const parent2 = node2.parentNode
  const nextNode1 = node1.nextSibling
  const nextNode2 = node2.nextSibling

  parent1.insertBefore(node2, nextNode1)
  parent2.insertBefore(node1, nextNode2)
}

const node1 = document.querySelector('.wrap1');
const node2 = document.querySelector('.wrap2');
swap(node1, node2);
```

```html
<div class="wrap1">wrap1</div>
<div class="wrap2">wrap2</div>
<div class="">skip1</div>
<div class="">skip2</div>
<div class="">skip3</div>
<div class="wrap3">wrap3</div>
<div class="wrap4">wrap4</div>
```

Немного хуже [решения Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1506571/184863) (не оптимизирует случай с соседством).